# Varnish configuration with domain names

Tags: configuration, varnish

I have configured Varnish and the configuration works fine when the host is specified with an ip address. But Varnish fails to start when the host is specified as a domain name (Say www.google.com).

This works. Varnish starts successfully and functionally everything is fine.

```
backend default {
    .host = "74.125.225.14";
    .port = "80";
}
```

This does NOT work, Varnish fails to start:

```
backend default {
    .host = "www.google.com";
    .port = "80";
}
```

Any idea on what could be wrong?

I do not have the logs right now, but will update the question once I have access to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Varnish does not support hostnames. Instead what we do is configure Apache (or some other proxy that does support hostnames) to listen on another local port and send Varnish traffic through that proxy.